# Rename categoryName in Categories

Tags: sql

I need rename name of the category Seafood to the Produce in CategoryName column.How should I rename?

```
UPDATE CategoryName
SET  CategoryName= 'Produce'
WHERE CategoryName = "Seafood"
```

Comment: What is the name of your table? Your query should be `update <table_name> set categoryName = 'Produce' where categoryName = 'Seafood'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "`UPDATE`" field, you should be updating the TABLE, not the COLUMN.

Your SET field is where you say what COLUMN you want to update. Your query should therefore look like

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET categoryName = 'Product'
WHERE categoryName = 'Seafood'
```

Answer (score 0):

The UPDATE syntax that you are using is incorrect. You did not mention table name anywhere in the query. Please specify table name. Specify databasename so the query would be executed against the correct database.

```
UPDATE <DatabaseName>.<schema>.<tablename> --CategoryName
SET  CategoryName= 'Produce'
WHERE CategoryName = "Seafood"
```

OR

```
USE <DATABASENAME>
GO

UPDATE <schema>.<tablename> --CategoryName 
SET  CategoryName= 'Produce'
WHERE CategoryName = "Seafood"
```

All UPDATE statements are [similar](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp). But if you are interested specifically please refer the links below:

- For syntax on SQL SERVER, please [refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
- For syntax on ORACLE, please [refer here](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj26498.html).
- For syntax on POSTGRES, please [refer here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update/).

Please search on GOOGLE if you are using any other database not listed above.